# Heroku rails assets fingerprint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'm new to rails and I'm having a problem with the assets in production: Heroku can't find the assets without the fingerprint.

For example, it finds:
**/assets/loading-8d5a7d189e11a76787df0a116636d069e821462ffb3aeca533943ca953b8a4ee.gif**

[image]

but it does not find:
**/assets/loading.gif**

[image]

Someone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: I think the probably more relevant question here is _why_ do you need the asset without the fingerprint? These assets aren't generated in production for a reason – you're meant to use the fingerprinted version. How come you need a non-fingerprinted asset?

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to use asset fingerprinting like that.

To use the gif, put it in assets/images, then in your view, use

```
<%=image_tag "loading.gif"%>
```